# How to get an index of multiple consecutive elements in R?

Tags: r, list, indexing, subset

I have two long lists, one of them is a consecutive subset of another.
Example:

```
full= c("cat", "dog", "giraffe", "gorilla", "opossum", "rat")
subset= c("giraffe", "gorilla", "opossum")
```

Is there an elegant way to get the index of where match starts, ends, or both?
In the example above, I would like to get 3 out since it is the index of "giraffe" in full text?

To clarify, if `subset= c("giraffe", "rat", "gorilla", "opossum")`
the output should be NA.

Comment: Do you need `match(subset, full)#
[1] 3 4 5`

Comment: To get the opposite index, perhaps `match(subset, rev(full))#
[1] 4 3 2`

Comment: No. Suppose subset= c("giraffe", "rat", "gorilla", "opossum"). Output should be NA.

Comment: What exactly do you want? only 3? ie the start?

Comment: Please consider to update your post with expected output so that it is clear

Comment: Index of the first if there is an exact match.

Comment: In that case `match(subset, full)[1]` and make a condition as well

Comment: @Onyambu i think that wouldn't work with the OP's new `subset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `match` with a condition

```
f1 <- function(subvec, fullvec) {
     i1 <- match(subvec, fullvec, nomatch = 0)
     if(any(diff(i1) != 1)) NA else i1[1]
}
```

-testing

```
> f1(subset, full)
[1] 3
> f1(subset2, full)
[1] NA
> f1(subset[c(1, 3)], full)
[1] NA
```

#### data

```
full <- c("cat", "dog", "giraffe", "gorilla", "opossum", "rat")
subset <-  c("giraffe", "gorilla", "opossum")
subset2 <-  c("giraffe", "rat", "gorilla", "opossum")
```

Comment: This is close (and I like the potential elegance of `match`), but unfortunately `match(subset[c(1,3)], full)` doesn't quite work.

Comment: I was thinking that the OP wanted in the same order.  If by consecutive the OP meant is no gaps, then the condition can be changed to `!= 1`

Answer (score 2):

```r
zoo::rollapply(full, 3, FUN = identical, subset)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
which(zoo::rollapply(full, 3, FUN = identical, subset))[1]
# [1] 3
zoo::rollapply(full, 3, FUN = func, c("giraffe", "rat", "gorilla", "opossum"))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
which(zoo::rollapply(full, 3, FUN = identical, c("giraffe", "rat", "gorilla", "opossum")))[1]
# [1] NA
```